# Iterating through an array to update screen

Tags: android, arrays

I have a list of names in an array, and clicking on on of these takes me to a record screen which displays the name and the code for that name. The information is provided in arrays of matching length. I want to be able to click on a button in the record screen that will take me to the corresponding screen for the next name.

I got the index i of the listView item from the intent, and then used it to get the right data for that name from the arrays.

Below is my code for the record screen.

```
public class RecordActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_record);

Intent intent = getIntent();
final int i = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_INDEX, 0);  

final String[]names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names);
final String[]codes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.codes);

final TextView nameView = new TextView(this);
nameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vNames);
String vName = names[i];
nameView.setText(vName);

TextView codeView = new TextView(this);
codeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vCodes);
String vCode = codes[i];
codeView.setText(vCode);

nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
    }});
}
```

In the onClick method in the button I want to do something like "set i=i+1, then refresh the data", but being new to programming I'm not entirely sure how to "write" this.

I've tried

```
if (i<names.length) {
  nameView.setText(names[i]);
  i++;}
```

but I got the error "The final local variable i cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type".

I want to keep this as general as possible because I'd like to have as many as 12 arrays calling the index to display the information.

Any ideas would be great thanks!

Comment: you cant change the value of i as you have set it as final which makes it a constant it stays at the value you have set for it. this is why you are getting your error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific problem you mention is here:

```
final TextView nameView = new TextView(this);
nameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vNames);
```

A field marked as final can be assigned only once.  In the first line, you assign a new TextView to it, which is completely redundant, since you want to assign a reference to the view from your layout in the next line, which then fails since the final nameView has already been assigned.

```
final TextView nameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vNames);
```

The same problem with i.  Simply remove the final keyword, or, if you intended it to be final, assign it to a different variable:

```
int x = i;
if (x<names.length) {
   nameView.setText(names[x]);
   x++;}
```

Comment: Thanks! That sorted that out. I've tried removing the 'final' from 'i' as suggested by @Roy but I now get "Cannot refer to a non-final variable i inside an inner class defined in a different method" (using Eclipse). How should I define i? And is there a simpler way to redefine the variable? Thanks

Comment: Yeh, that's true.  I guess that you are doing something in a click listener?  The code would help, but my guess is to use my suggestion of creating a new variable inside the method and assigning the value of i to it.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to put this in my button

    nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
    int x = i;
    if (x<names.length) {
    nameView.setText(names[x]);
    x++;
        }

With the code as you've suggested the app runs but the button doesn't seem to do anything. Am I missing some sort of command to update the screen maybe? Thanks

Comment: Probably time for a new question or we'll end up debugging your code line by line and comments is not good for that.  Please accept this answer then post your new code into a new question.  I suspect it's related to the fact that you only have one text view and you set it's value multiple times.  You will only ever see the last value.  Anyway, let's see.

Answer (score 0):

Dont set i final - instead use

```
this.i
```

to access it in the OnClickListener method. In normal coding convention you probably wouldnt use i as a variable but something more clear to indicate what it represents.